# how to run js file and store result in different file during jenkins deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins

I have a js file that returns an object on executing. I want to store this result in a different file and all these steps should proceed during the Jenkins deployment. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be creating the object in Js, it's best to handle storing of the object in JS as well.

If you want to store a JS object in a file, you should use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert the object into a string, then write the string to a file. You can allow the file to be created in the Jenkins workspace and as long as you don't clean the workspace the file will continue to be there. If you do clean the workspace after the build finishes you might want to store the file in a different location on your Jenkins host.

If you want to access the object later, read the file into a variable and use `JSON.parse(text)` to parse it into an object.

Comment: Can you share the command to achieve this during jenkins deployment for example sh "node Home.js"

Comment: You can simply add the JS code to the JS file that is running. Instead of returning the object, output the object as a Json file.